# java String replaceAll method replaces and creates empty space

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I have the following code

```
String str = "this is fun";
String str1 = str.replaceAll("is", "").trim();
System.out.println(str1);
```

The output is th" "     fun.

The 'is' in 'this' got removed but the space is still there, what needs to be done to remove that space. appreciate your help

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact string you are expecting?  `"This fun"`? `"Th fun"`? Something else?

Comment: So do you want the "is" in "this" to be replaced?

Comment: There are two spaces and no function to remove then, there's nothing wrong. `Trim()` would remove from the start or end of the `String`

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What should and should not be replaced?

Comment: Unfortunately when i enter space here looks like this is getting trimmed in the comment. so this is what i end up with "Th@@ fun" where "@@" is empty space replaced from "is"

Answer (score 1):

You can change the regular expression to match an *optional* space character. This way if `is` is followed by a space the it is removed, and yet, if there is no space, like when `is` happens to be in the middle of a word or at end of the input, it will still be removed.

```
String str = "this is fun";
String str1 = str.replaceAll("is ?", "").trim();
System.out.println(str1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do ->

```
String str1 = str.replaceAll("is", "").trim().replaceAll("  "," ");
```

With this, you are first replacing "is" with no space. Then you are replacing two spaces with single space. Hope this is what you want!

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
String str1 = str.replaceAll("is ", "");
```

Comment: Wondering if the OP needs to replace `"is"` occurring at the end of the string though.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "this is fun";
//modify String str1 = str.replaceAll("is", "").trim()
String str1 = str.replaceAll("is", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
System.out.println(str1);
```

Comment: If the `replaceAll` is there, is the `trim` strictly necessary?

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento I was just wondering in the scenarios where there *is* leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: @DennisMeng that's what I say too. If the input `String` is different from the example, the `trim()` would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an actual regular expression.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StringTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "this is fun";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*is");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    String str1 = matcher.replaceAll("").trim();
    System.out.println(str1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

From "this is fun" only "is" is replaced. Before and after second "is" are 2 " " spaces.
Maybe you want:

```
String str = "this is fun";
String str1 = str.replaceAll("is ", "").trim();
System.out.println(str1);
```

Or

```
String str = "this is fun";
String str1 = str.replaceAll(" is", "").trim();
System.out.println(str1);
```

Depends on which output you expect.

Comment: You arent answering the question he asked.